# What are some good examples of how structuralism is used in the humanities?

Tags: epistemology, philosophy-of-language

I'm aware that Levi-strauss used structuralist ideas in anthropology - are there any simple examples of how he used these ideas. I'm also aware of it being used in literature - how is that done. Are there good examples of this kind of analysis to look at?

Answer (score 3):

Basically, he used structuralist principles in two major ways:

- To situate his subject of study (kinship, food preparation, myths, etc.) within a larger frame such as the group or the culture.
- To establish dualities (*binary oppositions*) or other counter-balancing forces in the subject of study, along the lines of the distinctions made by Saussure when studying language (i.e. *parole* vs. *langue*).

For example, Lévi-Strauss proposed that myths must follow some kind of universal patterns, similar to archetypes if you wish; this makes myths from different cultures to be comparable, for instance. *The Savage Mind* and *The Raw and the Cooked* are two books by Lévi-Strauss where you can see the details of this.